# How to avoid wrapping ClassNames【Gutenberg RichText】

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I added the buttons for Large, Medium, Small Size Text on Gutenberg RichText Block by using create-guten-blocks.
These buttons add ClassName to the selected text when they are clicked.
They are working but when I click a button which already has ClassName, it wraps the another ClassName.
I mean they end up having double or triple ClassNames..

Like this below..

```
<span class="text-small"><span class="text-large">text<span><span>
```

How can I remove the previous ClassName when I click the one which has already ClassName?

Thank you.

```
     //Large Text
    var TextLarge = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
            icon: <svg xmlns="svg".../></svg>,
                title: 'Large Text,
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-blocks/text-large' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    var LButton = compose(
        withSelect( function( select ) {
            return {
                selectedBlock: select( 'core/editor' ).getSelectedBlock()
            }
        } ),
        ifCondition( function( props ) {
            return (
                props.selectedBlock &&
                props.selectedBlock.name !== 'core/heading'
            );
        } )
    )( TextLarge );

    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-blocks/text-large', {
            title: 'Large Text',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'text-large',
            edit: LButton,
        }
    );

    //Medium Text
    var TextMedium = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
            icon: <svg xmlns="svg".../></svg>,
                title: 'Medium Text',
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-blocks/text-medium' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    var MButton = compose(
        withSelect( function( select ) {
            return {
                selectedBlock: select( 'core/editor' ).getSelectedBlock()
            }
        } ),
        ifCondition( function( props ) {
            return (
                props.selectedBlock &&
                props.selectedBlock.name !== 'core/heading'
            );
        } )
    )( TextMedium );

    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-blocks/text-medium', {
            title: 'Medium Text',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'text-medium',
            edit: MButton,
        }
    );

    //Small Text
    var TextSmall = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
            icon: <svg xmlns="svg".../></svg>,
                title: 'Small Text',
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-blocks/text-small' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    var SButton = compose(
        withSelect( function( select ) {
            return {
                selectedBlock: select( 'core/editor' ).getSelectedBlock()
            }
        } ),
        ifCondition( function( props ) {
            return (
                props.selectedBlock &&
                props.selectedBlock.name !== 'core/heading'
            );
        } )
    )( TextSmall );

    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-blocks/text-small', {
            title: 'Small Text',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'text-small',
            edit: SButton,
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the logic I came up with. Let's say, that the **Medium** button is clicked:

1. Loop over active formats from the current RichText value and remove **Small** and **Large**, if found. This is done via the `wp.richText.removeFormat` function. Removing **Medium** will not allow us to track an active and inactive state and therefore impede the toggle functionality.
2. Call the `wp.richText.toggleFormat`, so we can have either **Medium** format or none.

My function looks like so (notice I am not that good at naming :D):

```
function removeActiveFormatsAndToggleSpecific(props, formatNameToSkip) {
   var propVal = props.value;
    var formattedItem = propVal;
    if (propVal.activeFormats.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < propVal.activeFormats.length; i++) {
            var typeOfFormat = propVal.activeFormats[i].type;
            if (typeOfFormat !== formatNameToSkip) {
                formattedItem = wp.richText.removeFormat(formattedItem, typeOfFormat);
            }
        }
    }
    formattedItem = wp.richText.toggleFormat(
        formattedItem,
        { type: formatNameToSkip });
    return formattedItem;
}
```

This function will be called in each individual `props.onChange` of the 3 buttons, so you will have to change your code like so:

```
var TextLarge = function( props ) {
    return wp.element.createElement(
        wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
        icon: <svg xmlns="svg".../></svg>,
            title: 'Large Text',
            onClick: function() {
                props.onChange(removeActiveFormatsAndToggleSpecific(props, 'my-blocks/text-large'));
            },
            isActive: props.isActive,
        }
    );
}
```

You will have to change the `onClick` function of the **Small** and **Medium** as well.

The `props.onChange` is called only once per internal cycle, which I am not familiar with, but I suspect it is set by react or the WordPress abstraction of it. Either way, I didn't manage to make changes with multiple onChange calls. It ended up executing only the last call, so I had to put everything in one function.

A few recommendations:

- I have written the code in ES5, as the code you wrote above, but I would suggest using [@wordpress/scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts), which allows for easy setup of a webpack build and you can use ESNext syntax.
- I would also recommend installing and importing all of the packages like `@wordpress/rich-text` and `@wordpress/editor` so you can lookup individual functions. Importing is not possible without a build step, so please implement the former first.
- I have the [Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/) installed, which provides the latest React code, which is to be implemented in future iterations of WordPress. It gives helpful tips and a lot of the console errors from the core code are cleared. It also gives hints about deprecated functionality. You will come to those messages sooner or later, so I would suggest using it today :) Here is what it said about your code: [image: Gutenberg warnings]